# ElementTree format for XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to `Line 28: root = ET.fromstring(res)`

My `res` contains Style Tags, Link Tags, script tags etc.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "helloworld.py", line 28, in <module>
        root = ET.fromstring(res)

    ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
        parser.feed(text)
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 2, column 0
```

My question is:
Do I have to remove all non HTML Tags to parse it properly?

Q2: Is it necessary to pretty print for proper parsing?

Sorry, I just started today if this is basic stuff.

**EDIT**: Using lxml now. I've got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hendrik\Desktop\Python\helloworld.py", line 28, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse(res)
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:81101)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1811, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:117832)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1837, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:118179)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1741, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:117091)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1138, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:111637)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105093)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106801)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105612)
OSError: Error reading file '
```

res (HTML) contains script tags, link tags, etc.

Why is this error thrown an how to workaround it, can't find solution on the web just for IOError...

***SOLUTION***:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
root   = etree.fromstring(f, parser)
```

then I could successfully

```
root.xpath(...)
```

and extract needed information.

Comment: see here: http://lxml.de/parsing.html - in other words, use the html parser, not the xml parser. also try BeautifulSoup...

Comment: Thanks, i editted my question, additionally is it possible to run xpath expressions with lxml?

Comment: yes you can run xpaths.

Comment: if you specify url to scrap someone may help you in getting the data too.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.1, which lxml version do I need?

Comment: try with latest one

Comment: As long as `res` is well-formed XML, it can be parsed. The XML does not need to be pretty-printed. If you need more help, consider creating a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, I've editted my post, do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: @mzjin It's a web scraping project, so for example stackoverflow.com website source code :)

Comment: If it's HTML that you are parsing, try `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree`. http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Answer (score 0):

***SOLUTION*** 
to OSError while parsing HTML

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
root   = etree.fromstring(f, parser)
```

then I could successfully

```
root.xpath(...)
```

and extract needed information.

Comment: Whats that "f" on (f, parser)?

Comment: @pojda f is the string